# Only Index the fields that are present in mappings - ElasticSearch v5.2.2

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

While creating mapping for mine type `type1` i have declared 3 fields,

But while indexing the data, the `body` can have many other fields too that are not present in mine `mapping`

```
esClient.indices.putMapping({
    index: 'index1',
    type: 'type1',
    body: {
        properties: {
            Name: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            Description: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            Address: {
                type: 'string',
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Here, the `data` object have two more fields `class` and `organization`, ElasticSearch will by default create the types for the extra fields that are not mentioned in mine mappings.

```
const data = {
    Name: 'pauline',
    Description: 'he\'s pauline from academy',
    Address: 'avenue street',
    class: 'Standard form 1', // ignore this while indexing
    organization: 'Escalar Communications' // ignore this while indexing
}
```

So, Is there a way to only index the fields data that are present in the `_mappings` and exclude the others, I mean some options to set.

OR I have to do it mineself

```
esClient.index({
    index: 'index1',
    type: 'type1',
    body: data,
}, (error, response) => {
    console.log(error, response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by adding `"dynamic": false` to your mapping to ignore fields that are not in your mapping. By default it is true.

```
esClient.indices.putMapping({
    index: 'index1',
    type: 'type1',
    body: {
        dynamic: false,               <--- add this
        properties: {
            Name: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            Description: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            Address: {
                type: 'string',
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You need to delete your index and recreate it

Comment: yes, i did that too, deleted the index, created it, did mine mappings with body object set with `dyanmic:false` and indexed the data with extra fields, the extra fields indexed.

Comment: Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index1/_mapping/type1` ?

Comment: what version of ES are you running?

Comment: 5.2.2, setting `default: "strict"` will through an error when the extra fields are found, but i want it to through an error and other fields that are matched with mine `mappings` to be indexed. Is there a way to do that

Comment: Yeah `strict` throws an error and that's not what you want. `false`should work, not sure why it isn't

Comment: In your gist, you have "false" and not false as a boolean variable. Perhaps this is why it doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference